# Calculate and define a constant in class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If a value of the constant is a pure constant, than it is very easy to define it:

```
class Foo {
    static get bar() { return 123; }
}
```

However, what if I need to define a constant that needs to be calculated in the constructor?

```
class Foo {
  constructor(m) {
    // ...
  }
}

let test = new Foo(10);
console.log(test.bar);  // OK
test.bar = 1;           // ERROR
```

How can I define `bar` within the constructor and make this bar accessible as a constant?

---

The value of this constant is needed many times in other methods. The calculation of this constant value is not trivial, so it would be a waste of resources to calculate it each time when it is needed. On the other hand, I want to ensure that it can't be changed once it is calculated.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, but could you memoize the calculation result as a workaround?

Comment: @AlexanderNied - Memorize it to a variable? Variable can be changed. That is not a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## UPDATE

Per the discussion in the comments, this can be achieved even more cleanly by simply setting a `value` property in the config passed to [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) in lieu of a `get` property; because the `writable` and `configurable` properties default to `false`, this is sufficient in providing the desired behavior outlined in the question:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(m) {
    this.m = m;
    const bar = m * 100;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'bar', { value: bar });
  }
}

let test = new Foo(10);

console.log(test.bar);
test.bar = 300;
console.log(test.bar);
delete test.bar;
console.log(test.bar);
```

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

One option would be to use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) in the constructor to set a `getter` for `bar`, and a `setter` that prevented its being changed:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(m) {
    this.m = m;
    const bar = m * 100;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'bar', {
     get: () => bar,
        set: () => console.warn('bar cannot be set'), // The setter is optional
    });
  }
}

let test = new Foo(10);

console.log(test.bar);
test.bar = 300;
console.log(test.bar);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that `set` really needed?

Comment: Good question.  I don't believe that it is required, although it's possible that there might be some linters that would call you out on it.

Comment: What's the point of using a getter if it returns a constant value and doesn't compute anything?

Comment: @Thomas It fulfills the requirements of the question: it allows the read but not written, and doesn't need to make the same calculation repeatedly.  My calculation in the example is trivial, but for Ωmega's use case the calculation is apparently quite expensive.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your objection or some better solution?

Comment: But you can do that with a value, without a getter. So what's the getter for?

Comment: _But you can do that with a value, without a getter._ I'm not sure I follow.  You can make it available with a value as an instance property, but then it is possible for it to be changed, which was what Ωmega was trying to avoid.  My apologies if I am missing something obvious-- perhaps you could provide a JSFiddle that illustrates your point?

Comment: You can set a few more thing with a property descriptor: `var a = {}; console.log("initial", a.foo); Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", { configurable: true, value: 42 }); console.log("defined configurable", a.foo); a.foo = 30; console.log("assigned value, failed", a.foo); Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", { configurable: false, value: 13 }); console.log("redefined successfully", a.foo); a.foo = 30; console.log("assign value still fails", a.foo); Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", { value: 14 }); console.log("redefine now also fails", a.foo);`

Comment: @Thomas - OK, I think I understand the point you are making.  [I've taken the liberty of moving your comment to a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anied/5pe31Lh2/3/).  I believe you are trying to illustrate that setting a `value` in `defineProperty` is sufficient in creating a read-only property on an object, which would make a `getter` unnecessary.  This is a fair point; I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
class Foo {
    constructor (m) {
        this._bar = m + 10; // this is _bar , not bar
    }

    get bar() {
        return this._bar; //_bar is the private methods, which is different from bar
    }
}


const foo = new Foo(1);
console.log(foo.bar) // return 11
foo.bar =  0
console.log(foo.bar) // still return 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(value) {
       this._privateValue = value;
    }
    get bar() {
        return this._privateValue;
    }
    set bar(val) {
        console.error("Sorry can't edit me ;) ")
    }
}

const test = new Foo(10)
console.log(test.bar)
test.bar = 20;
console.log(test.bar)
```

Comment: So you have a public "private property" and a public getter that returns the value of the other property.